# Função em JS para calcular idade em meses e anos

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa função, porem quando roda o mês sempre está dando +12 meses, como se a pessoa já tivesse feito aniversário. Como poderia concertar?

```js
let daysH = document.getElementById("date");
let monthH = document.getElementById("month");
let yearH = document.getElementById("year");

let showAge = document.getElementById("show-age");




const btn = document.getElementById("calc-btn");

var today = new Date();
let d = today.getDate();
var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
var y = today.getFullYear();
let maxDays = 0;
let monthNum = 1;

btn.addEventListener("click", (days, month, year) => {

  days = daysH.value;
  month = monthH.value;
  year = yearH.value;

  if (daysH.value == "" || monthH.value == "" || yearH.value == "") {
    return alert("Por favor, preencha seu dados")
  }

  // no else condition needed

  console.log(`Current Date : ${d} ${m} ${y}`);

  if (m == 1) { // janeiro
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 1;
  } else if (m == 2) { // fevereiro
    maxDays = 28;
    monthNum = 2;
  } else if (m == 3) { // março
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 3;
  } else if (m == 4) { // abril
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 4;
  } else if (m == 5) { // maio
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 5;
  } else if (m == 6) { // junho
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 6;
  } else if (m == 7) { // julho
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 7;
  } else if (m == 8) { // agosto
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 8;
  } else if (m == 9) { // setembro
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 9;
  } else if (m == 10) { // outubro
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 10;
  } else if (m == 11) { // novembro
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 11;
  } else { //dezembro
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 12;
  }





  var ageYears = y - year;

  if (m <= month) {
    m = m + 12;
  }
  var ageMonths = m - month;
  var ageDays = (maxDays - d) + parseInt(days);

  console.log(`Sua Idade é ${ageYears} a , ${ageMonths} m and ${ageDays} d`);
  showAge.innerHTML = `Sua Idade é ${ageYears} a , ${ageMonths} m and ${ageDays} d`;
})
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="input">Qual a data do seu nascimento? </label>
  <input type="number" id="date" placeholder="data">
  <input type="number" id="month" placeholder="mês">
  <input type="number" id="year" placeholder="ano">

  <button id="calc-btn">Calculate Age</button>

  <p id="show-age"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: então, eu preciso que calcule os meses e dias também

Comment: O Stack Overflow em Português [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum), nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas. Não usem o campo de respostas para trocar comunicação. Ou [editem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/492606/edit) a pergunta acrescentando detalhes e esclarecimento ou usem o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) para uma comunicação mais ativa.

Answer (score -3):

Resolucao do problema.[EDITADO]

```
        let daysH = document.getElementById("date");
        let monthH = document.getElementById("month");
        let yearH = document.getElementById("year");

        let showAge = document.getElementById("show-age");




        const btn = document.getElementById("calc-btn");

        var today = new Date();
        let d = today.getDate();
        var m = today.getMonth() +1;
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        let maxDays = 0;
        let monthNum = 1;

        btn.addEventListener("click", (days, month, year) => {

            days = daysH.value;
            month = monthH.value;
            year = yearH.value;

            if (daysH.value == "" || monthH.value == "" || yearH.value == "") {
                return alert("Por favor, preencha seu dados")
            }

            // no else condition needed

            console.log(`Current Date : ${d} ${m} ${y}`);

            if (m == 1) { // janeiro
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 1;
            }
            else if (m == 2) { // fevereiro
                maxDays = 28;
                monthNum = 2;
            }
            else if (m == 3) { // março
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 3;
            }
            else if (m == 4) { // abril
                maxDays = 30;
                monthNum = 4;
            }
            else if (m == 5) { // maio
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 5;
            }
            else if (m == 6) { // junho
                maxDays = 30;
                monthNum = 6;
            }
            else if (m == 7) { // julho
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 7;
            }
            else if (m == 8) { // agosto
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 8;
            }
            else if (m == 9) { // setembro
                maxDays = 30;
                monthNum = 9;
            }
            else if (m == 10) { // outubro
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 10;
            }
            else if (m == 11) { // novembro
                maxDays = 30;
                monthNum = 11;
            }

            else { //dezembro
                maxDays = 31;
                monthNum = 12;
            }

            var ageYears = y - year;

            ageYears = ageYears - monthNum;

            // if (m <= month) {
            //     m = m + 12;
            // }
            
            var ageMonths = month - m;
            var ageDays = (maxDays - d) + parseInt(days);

            console.log(`Sua Idade é ${ageYears} a , ${ageMonths} m and ${ageDays} d`);
            showAge.innerHTML = `Sua Idade é ${ageYears} a , ${ageMonths} m and ${ageDays} d`;
        })
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119172/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-bafilli-funcao-em-js-para-calcular-idade-em-meses) ... para outras conversas, informais recomendo o chat oficial: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha